# Bash: how do I convert a command with a number result then compare it with an operator

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, operators

I am trying to execute a word count command on a log file and if the file has the "error" string, I want to take some action, but I can't seem to properly convert the grep to word count command to a real number so it compares properly to the greater than zero.  So far with several variations, the conditional statement is always true.

`if ((grep -Ei "error" myfile.log | wc -l)) > 0; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi`

Comment: I believe `grep` will already provide an exit status of 0 (success) if it finds the string and 1 (error) if it doesn't. So you don't need word count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can write conditions based on the exit code of programs.
If `grep` finds a matching line, it exits with success:

```
if grep -qEi "error" myfile.log; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

I added the `-q` flag to not print the matching line, as you probably don't need it.

---

I strongly recommend to use the above solution, without `wc`.
But for the sake of completeness, here's some more explanation about different ways of comparing numbers.

One way to compare numbers is with `-gt` ("greater than") within `[ ... ]`:

```
if [ $(grep -Ei "error" myfile.log | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

You can read about other operators within `[ ... ]` in `help test`.

Or using arithmetic context within `((...))`:

```
if (($(grep -Ei "error" myfile.log | wc -l) > 0)); then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Notice that in both of these examples I wrapped the `grep ... | wc -l` within a `$(...)` sub-shell to capture the output.
The syntax you wrote is incorrect.